# C# Timer Interval doesn't work

Tags: c#, timer, tweetsharp

As written in the title, something in the Timer Interval seems to be off. The timer should take the time from a "DateTimePicker", convert it to seconds & change the Interval to the time set on the DateTimePicker. Afterwards it should post a tweet on twitter, though it doesn't work. It just keeps spamming posts over and over.

```
            private void IntervalChoose_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //DateTimePicker
    {
        postInterval.Interval = (IntervalChoose.Value.Hour * 3600) + (IntervalChoose.Value.Minute * 60) + IntervalChoose.Value.Second;
        saveTimerInterval = postInterval.Interval; //saveTimerInterval is set 0 at the beginning
        MessageBox.Show("Current Interval in Seconds: " + postInterval.Interval.ToString());
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.Text == "Start Bot") //Starts program (works)
        {
            IntervalChoose.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show(saveTimerInterval.ToString());
            postInterval.Interval = saveTimerInterval; //Sets the interval (once again, safecall)
            postInterval.Start(); //starts posting.
            button1.Text = "Stop Bot";
        }
    private void postInterval_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var service = new TwitterService("", "", "", ""); //Auth Keys
        var twitterStatus = service.SendTweet(new SendTweetOptions() { Status = "Hi" + counter });
        if (twitterStatus != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your Message:\n\n\"" + "Hi" + counter + "\"\n\n has been successfully tweeted.", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            counter++;

        }
        else
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("An Error occured while the Bot was running. Please Contact the Developer.", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    label2.Text = "Next Post in:\n" + (postInterval.Interval / 3600) + " Hour(s) " + ((postInterval.Interval / 3600) / 60) + " Minute(s) " + (((postInterval.Interval / 3600) / 60) / 60) + " Second(s)";
    }
```

Result:

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

As seen in the Pictures, the label won't refresh, nor the new set time is being used. It just randomly posted text in a random time.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You know `Interval` is milliseconds right? Also, don't use a timer this way. Set it to `tick` every second, then in the `tick` event check if the scheduled time has elapsed, if so then send and clear the 'task', otherwise do nothing

Comment: Or that you can get the time portion from a DateTime by using the TimeOfDay property? That returns a TimeSpan whose `TotalMilliseconds` property returns the time as milliseconds? You can write `postInterval.Interval = (int)IntervalChoose.Value.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;`

Comment: lmao I totally forgot it was MS; I'll try out @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned, the `Interval` property expects *milliseconds*, not seconds. In any case, you *don't* need to make the conversions by hand. A DateTimePicker returns a DateTime value. You can get the time portion of a DateTime as a TimeSpan using the [DateTime.TimeOfDay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx) property. The timespan's properties return the various time parts, or the total duration measured in a specific unit. For example, [TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the current time value as milliseconds.

All you need to write is:

```
postInterval.Interval = (int)IntervalChoose.Value.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
```

That takes care of the invalid interval problem and works only if you want eg to send a message every 10 minutes or every 1 hour.

If you want to send a message at a set time you can't use a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) because it doesn't allow you to set a specific start time or start delay. In this case you'd have to use [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah1h85ch(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

The [Timer.Interval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property has this documentation:

> The time, **in milliseconds**, between Elapsed events. The value must be greater than zero, and less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue. The default is 100 milliseconds.

*(my emphasis)*

So 3930 milliseconds is just slightly quicker than every 4 seconds.

---

A different way to implement this is to calculate the DateTime of when the next post should be submitted, then run the timer "often enough", say once every second, and just check if the current computer time has passed that calculated DateTime value.

If it has, do whatever, then calculate the next point in time it should run.

Answer (score 0):

At first that I see, you set Interval in seconds. But you need set it in milliseconds postInterval.Interval = ((IntervalChoose.Value.Hour * 3600) + (IntervalChoose.Value.Minute * 60) + IntervalChoose.Value.Second)*1000;

Comment: Well even with that you are going to be creating an Internal based on midnight. So it will only work as expected if the user sets the bot at exactly midnight. A correct interval would need to factor the current time of date into the calculation